# changing the directory and executing the makefile commands

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have the following directory structure

```
project
|-- aws-cdk
|-- data
    |-- some_project_files
    |-- Makefile
```

Using the `Makefile`, I'm executing the directory `some_project_files` and this is working fine. In addition to that, I want to execute `aws-cdk` as well. But I do not see a way to change the directory within the makefile. I tried `cd aws-cdk` and then execute but I keep on getting error `make: *** No rule to make target. Stop.`

How do I go back/change directory and then execute Makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within one makefile you can change directory inside the rules, but you can't say this set of rules runs in one directory and this one runs in the other. Which does not prevent you running rules on files in a different directory by simply giving their path. The `data/Makefile` can contain rules for `../aws-cdk/something` and even `../aws-cdk/%.out: ../aws-cdk/%.in` and that's just fine.

If you do want to actually change directory, you need a separate makefile. I strongly recommend just putting it in the directory where it will run, so `aws-cdk/Makefile` and then you can just call it from the one in `data` like `$(MAKE) -C ../aws-cdk`. You can also put it anywhere else and give make an explicit argument like `$(MAKE) -C ../aws-cdk -f aws-cdk.make`, but putting it in the directory will be easier to understand when it needs fixing two years down the line and/or by someone who's never seen it.